# I want to script a link in a column of my view based on the pKey column of the table

Tags: html, sql

I have an online program that holds records based on their ID number (the pKey). I have to provide a file to an external source where they would like the last column of the dataset to reference each individual records url in the online program. How can I write my view to put each row's ID number into the url?

whole url = Example\webprorgam\List\item='IDnumber'

ex: Row1IDnumber....Data....Url+'Row1IDnumber'

I thought I might be able to do it with a CASE statement but I am not sure how to get the 'THEN' portion to reference the ID number within the CASE

I need to do this in SQL Server; any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would create a [Table Value Function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as another layer over the view. This allows the base part of the URL to be kept in your program somewhere and not hard-coded in your SQL.

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myTableFunction(
  @pURLBase AS VarChar(MAX)
) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
  SELECT *, @pURLBase + Cast(Row1IDNumber AS VarChar) AS WholeURL FROM myView;
```

Then you can consume the function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.myTableFunction('Example\webprorgam\List\item=');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    IDNumber,
    otherFields,
    concat('http://yourcompany.com/Example/webprogram/List/item=', IDNumber) as url
from
    yourTable
```

Comment: I would use this but I am in version 2008 R2 so its not built in :(